# 20 questions quiz game app problems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to write a Twenty-Questions app for school, and I've hit a speed bump.

On line 26, I'm getting the error: `20q2.rb:26: warning: string literal in condition`.

Also, I have a scoring system to tell the user what their final score is and it's printing the score after every question when it's supposed to be displayed at the end of the quiz.

The code works fine otherwise, so if anyone that can help me with the two problems I'm having that would be great.

Here's the code:

```
#list quesions in an array

QANDA = [["Is the sky blue?", "y"],["Is it dark at night?", "y"],                                  
["Is this a yes or no question?", "y"],
["Is this a short answer question", "n"],
["Is this program written in rails?", "n"],["Is this program written in ruby?", "y"]]
#create a variable for the scoring system
num = 0
#create a loop to ask questions automatically
QANDA.each do |options|
puts options[0]
#ask for user input
puts "enter y or n"
ans = gets.chomp
ansdown = ans.downcase
#compair user input with correct answer
if ansdown == options[1]
#add number to score and give praise
num = num + 1
puts "correct"
#give shame
elsif ansdown == "n"
puts "incorrect"
#reprint question if responce is invalid
end
if ansdown != "y" && "n" && "Y" && "N"
puts "invaild input, please try again. Enter y/n only."
    redo
end
#convert num to a string
score = num.to_s
#print score
puts "you got " + score + " of 6 questions right."
#shame the foolish
if num <= 3
puts "you did a pretty bad job"
#praise the wise
elsif num > 4
puts "great job!"
elsif num == 4
puts "not to bad"
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ansdown != "y" && "n" && "Y" && "N"
```

This line doesn't make sense to me beyond the first condition. You need to fix this according to what you want done. This is the "string literal" warning.

It is only a warning and strings are considered true in Ruby, but I am guessing thats not what you want.

I suggest

```
unless ["y","n"].include? ansdown
```

You need to downcase but you are already doing that.

As for the second issue, please improve your indentation. I expect your score code is in too deep. It should be outside the `each` block

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting an error at the end of the code. Do you have any idea what could be causing that?
20q2.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: if you fix your indenting, you might find that one of your blocks arent closed.. that is what the error sounds like.

Answer (score 1):

The following condition is wrong:

```
 if ansdown != "y" && "n" && "Y" && "N"
```

as it will be interpreted as following:

```
 if (ansdown != "y")     &&      ("n")     &&       ("Y")     &&     ("N")
```

What you may want to do is:

```
 if ansdown != "y" && ansdown != "n" && ansdown != "Y" && ansdown != "N"
```

or in short you can do this:

```
 if !["y", "Y","n","N"].include?(ansdown)
```

if you are using ActiveSupport, you can use `exclude?` also (not possible in pure Ruby):

```
 if ["y", "Y","n","N"].exclude?(ansdown)
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'm getting an error at the end of the code. Do you have any idea what could be causing that?
20q2.rb:40: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Comment: That means, you have somewhere one extra `end` or excess of it. Indent your code properly, which can help identifying this.